# 'cannot be resolved to a type' error when importing web project

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, import, autowired

I have downloaded this sample java-based web application : https://github.com/loiane/ext4-crud-mvc and now I'm trying to import it to eclipse. I was hoping it will work out of the box, but unfortunately after the operation IDE is throwing errors at me :

`Autowired cannot be resolved to a type` and indicates error in line 101 of https://github.com/loiane/ext4-crud-mvc/blob/master/src/br/com/braziljs/loiane/web/ContactController.java and every other place where '@Classname' construction appears.

It's my first time using Eclipse, first time with java web app and a few years after last time developing with Java so I'm not really sure where to start to fix this.

Comment: hmm I've added the libs in the project settings and it looks to be solved. If you'll add this as an answer I can +1 you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add all required jar files to build path?

Comment: How do you do that?